# Getting the error in custom query "ResultTransformer is not allowed for 'select new' queries"

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have written a query and it is giving this error:

```
ResultTransformer is not allowed for 'select new' queries
```

Not sure why it is happening.

```
StringBuilder q = new StringBuilder();
q.append(" SELECT  DISTINCT new map(p as plan, pei.stateCodeId as state)  ");
q.append(" FROM  PlanEligibilityIndex pei ");
```

The above query is where I have written that select new, and it is giving this error trace.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: ResultTransformer is not allowed for 'select new' queries.
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.checkQuery(QueryLoader.java:509) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:503) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:395) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1508) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1537) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1505) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    ... 143 common frames omitted
```

Comment: try to simplify and see what happens:

1. remove DISTINCT.
 2. remove column aliasing.

Comment: can you show the portion of code where the query is executed?

Comment: @KonstantinTriger No luck. Still failing and giving same error

Comment: give full resolved name for the map class

Comment: @KonstantinTriger Thanks for helping out, Its working now

Answer (score 1):

Removing DISTINCT from select query worked for me.